# iOS google reverse geocode not working properly

Tags: objective-c, ios9, nsurlsession, sendasynchronousrequest, nsurlsessiondatatask

For reverse geocoding am using the following method,

```
[api getRequest:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=%f,%f&key=%@&language=%@",latV,lonV,kGoogleAPIKey,@"en"] withCompletionHandle:^(NSData *data) {

    NSMutableDictionary *returnedDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSLog(@"the data value returned %@",returnedDict);
```

This link didn't work for me always it say request timed out or some other error,

rarely am getting the response properly,

can't understand why this happening, one in the iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus in iOS 9, sometimes am getting the response properly but sometimes i can't

Am getting this error sometimes

```
This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
 Stack:(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186304f74 <redacted> + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000019aefbf80 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000186304ea4 <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x000000018731e5d8 <redacted> + 88
    4   Foundation                          0x00000001871a0a1c <redacted> + 36
    5   UIKit                               0x000000018c0826a0 <redacted> + 884
    6   UIKit                               0x000000018c083b14 <redacted> + 788
    7   UIKit                               0x000000018c14ca6c <redacted> + 480
    8   UIKit                               0x000000018c149a44 <redacted> + 172
    9   UIKit                               0x000000018c149cb4 <redacted> + 96

10  UIKit                               0x000000018c14a178 <redacted> + 80
11  UIKit                               0x000000018c14e5c4 <redacted> + 492
12  UIKit                               0x000000018c14d878 <redacted> + 164
13  UIKit                               0x000000018c14d7a8 <redacted> + 284
14  UIKit                               0x000000018bcaa700 <redacted> + 444
15  UIKit                               0x000000018bcaa7d4 <redacted> + 60
16  UIKit                               0x000000018bcaa914 <redacted> + 28
17  UIKit                               0x000000018bca9f08 <redacted> + 100
18  UIKit                               0x000000018b85b610 <redacted> + 1124
19  UIKit                               0x000000018b85b194 <redacted> + 28
20  UIKit                               0x000000018bbcdbfc <redacted> + 108
21  UIKit                               0x000000018bbc6e58 <redacted> + 1328
22  UIKit                               0x000000018bbc8840 <redacted> + 4428
23  UIKit                               0x000000018bbcb278 <redacted> + 472
24  UIKit                               0x000000018b9520a4 <redacted> + 184
25  UIKit                               0x000000018c13d324 <redacted> + 512
26  UIKit                               0x000000018c13b8d8 <redacted> + 228
27  UIKit                               0x000000018bcb8328 <redacted> + 260
28  Mawgif                              0x0000000100177534 __63-[APIService_Request_Response getRequest:withCompletionHandle:]_block_invoke + 628
29  CFNetwork                           0x0000000185a1349c <redacted> + 32
30  CFNetwork                           0x0000000185a26454 <redacted> + 296
31  Foundation                          0x000000018722782c <redacted> + 16
32  Foundation                          0x000000018717a6c0 <redacted> + 96
33  Foundation                          0x000000018716a918 <redacted> + 604
34  Foundation                          0x0000000187229c20 <redacted> + 224
35  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101ec5d30 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101ed27f0 _dispatch_queue_drain + 1036
37  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101ec9a20 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 464
38  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101ed4908 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 760
39  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000101ed4600 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 132
40  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019b909478 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
41  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000019b909028 start_wqthread + 4
```

)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on "some other error"?

Comment: What is returned when you copy your URI into a browser window and execute the request from there?

Comment: @HermannKlecker am getting the response properly on web

Comment: How are latV and lonV declared and filled with data? The same for kGoogleAPIKey. (You can x-out the actual key)

Comment: @HermannKlecker am getting reverse geocoding properly on web , but when i do that on my mobile it gives the response sometimes but most of the time it didnt

Comment: How are latV and lonV declared and filled with data? The same for kGoogleAPIKey. (You can x-out the actual key) - You must show some code.

Comment: @HermannKlecker, for latV,lonV and kGoogleAPIKey am having the value and pass it correctly

Comment: Thanks for the stack trace. This error message is hardly related to the original problem. It just states that you are modifying the UI from another thread than the UI thread.

Comment: I guess,the error doesnt seem to related to the code you are using, as the error says it is related to autolayout, you are doing something crazy to the UI layout.

Comment: Did you set a breakpiont in the completion handler? Do you set an error handler too? Where did you get this URI from? Did you log it to the debug console? PLEASE show more code!

Comment: @Mr.T actually Am using only google maps sdk to show the map autolyout is impletmented properly buddy, But sometimes am receiving the response

Comment: @HermannKlecker Sometimes I got the error , but sometimes it got timed out

Comment: @HermannKlecker yes i did with breakpoint for error handler